# Excel error "This workbook contains Excel 4.0 macros or Excel 5.0 modules"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that was protected via the Protect Workbook feature.  It was sent to someone else to modify.  When they sent it back, it was unprotected and when I try to reprotect it I get this error,

> "This workbook contains Excel 4.0
>   macros or Excel 5.0 modules.  If you
>   would like to password protect or
>   restrict permission to this document,
>   you need to remove these macros."

I looked and there are no new macros in the edited file.  The original file contained the same macros and it was able to be write protected, so I'm not sure why the modified file is having a problem.  What are common causes and solutions for this error and does it make sense for the modified file to have the error when the original doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking "Protect Workbook" then deselecting "Protect Structures and Windows". It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the following is for anyone searching on the issue and needing a solution. I'm sure the poster has long stopped caring!

The only reasons for the message fall into two main classes:

1. The someone who had the file enabled in general in his copy of Excel the use of the Excel 4 (and 5, but that's what people call them) macros, commands and macro pages both, and could actually have created literal macros. Different looking than VBA macros, to be sure, but once you saw them you'd catch on very fast.

Not likely.

2. The someone who had the file `used one of the viable (for this kind of use) Excel 4 macro commands` in a Named Range. This is VERY likely what has happened.

Since the Excel 4 macro commands ARE macro commands, using them, whether in a literal macro or in Named Ranges will trigger Excel to treat the spreadsheet as having macros in it. Up till around the start of 2021, you could save the file you were using them in (in Named Ranges for this point, not actual macros) and during the save, Excel would warn you to save the file as a macro-enabled file (i.e.:  .XLSM, not .XLSX). You could say "No!" and the save would work like usual, and this chiding would never come up again. Opening the file gave no warnings and the formulas in the Named Ranges worked just fine.

For the last year and a bit, it no longer lets that happen. If you refuse to use the .XLSM format, the Excel 4 functions are gone when you open it next and cell formulas using the Named Ranges they were part of are busted. If you DO use the .XLSM format, well, lots of people won't open your spreadsheet. But the formulas the Named Ranges use will work if they do.

That second one is surely what you need to explore. Open the Name Manager and begin examining Named Ranges, looking at their `Refers to` content (usually a formula or range). You are looking for any Excel 4 function name.

For example, `EVALUATE()` is a wonderful function from the Excel 4 macro language and has absolutely no modern equivalent. None at all, or even close. If you got the spreadsheet back from me and this message came up, that's the function I might have used 7-8 times out of 10. (Of course, I would NEVER have left that obvious of a sign that I broke the protection (easiest thing in the world) and did my pleasure with your spreadsheet. Others are more careless or just don't care, sad to say.)

In any case, ANY function you spot that you do not recognize can be checked in one of two easy ways. You can search the internet for the function. If it is one of the Excel 4 macro commands, you will absolutely see that fact in the first hit or two you follow up on. Folks want you to know they know something you do not, and this is a fun one to imagine you are wowing people with.

The other way is even easier. Simply go to a cell and start a formula with the function and while you are typing the function name in, see if the `Intellisense` help comes up, or not. If not, you found one of them (other guy may have used more). And finish out the function, then press Enter and see if it errors with `#NAME!` or does... anything else. Any that do that error are one of them.

At this point, or before doing anything else, actually, you could contact the other guy and say "Hey, did you do some of this kind of thing?" Lots of folks would be sheepish and go "Oh, um, yeah..." and help you clean things up. Quite a few though would clam up and stare at you like you've just grown antlers so:

Remove all such Named Ranges if you did not create them. That's the likeliest thing. And uses of them in the spreadsheet that the other guy left lying about will fail, but you didn't want them anyway. Run them down and delete them or fix them as appropriate. This could be simple with fairly noticeable uses and either deletion or simple fixes. Could be pretty complicated, especially if the person did try to clean up and left a real mess.

There's an `outside the question itself` set of factors to consider vis-a-vis ever working with that person again without managerial supervision over the horrid work he does, but this is meant for someone searching the more general problem and needing a way forward, and probably preferring a non-confrontational way forward at that.

Finally, it is possible, though exceedingly unlikely given he was to modify it somehow and present it back, presumably for general use. While he might not have been aware of the MS steps to tighten the screws on uses of those commands (companies can now close them off altogether via the Trust Center and enterprise policies, which, while it might've been possible before, it was not something the program actively brought up before) as they finally get serious about them going away for the first time in 25 years, he surely could not have thought to keep his job writing actual Excel 4 macros themselves. But if he did, those were placed upon special pages inserted for them and would be pretty easy to spot. If he did that kind of thing though, seriously speaking his modifications are completely unusable outside his computer as no one else will accept them. Go back to the original that was sent to him and find a different way to get the spreadsheet modified.

I say that as a person who has enabled them in my copy of Excel but who would never foist them upon others as acceptable work. They are for my own work, and rarely used. Definitely not to hand off to others.